# What is the plausability of biomechanical muscle mass?

Tags: medicine, bio-mechanics, medical

So in my story, the protaganist has had an accident where most of his muscles have to be rebuilt. The medical staff do a procedure in which they give him cybernetic muscles, and I'm thinking that they use some sort of material that works similar to human muscle I.E. it is controlled by nerve impulses rather than by servo motors etc. I was just wondering about the feasibilty of this and if it would have the added advantage of him being able to go for a while without food. After all the mucsles wouldn't need protein and wouldn't be subjet to lactic acid buildup etc.

Comment: Question1: Power supply. Since it isn't receiving energy from food, it needs to get it from somewhere. What is supplying the power? Question 2: Waste. Does your power supply produce any byproducts? How are these disposed of? What happens to the heat generated by the artificial muscle? Question 3: Wear. Any moving part will wear down. Biological parts are constantly repaired by the body. How is your artificial muscle repaired and how often do you need to do it?

Comment: 1) I was thinking that the power supply would be the electrical impulses from the nerves, like some sort of material that contracts when an electrical stimulant is passed through it. 2) No waste and the heat would be dissipated through skin and sweat just like heat generated by biological muscle. 3) Once or twice a year depending on the strenousness of the movement.

Comment: Point 1: Nope. Think of your servo motor example. It takes a minimum of 3 input wires: One is the control signal, which tells the motor to start or stop and which direction to spin; one is common ground or negative; and the last one supplies the power to actually move the thing. Law of conservation of energy: if you want 1 Joule of work you have to put in 1 Joule or more of energy. It's why we have blood vessels in addition to nerves in our bodies. The nerves supply the control signals, the blood the energy in the for of nutrients and oxygen. It also removes waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are piezoelectric polymers (I think that's the right term) which can be deformed and/or stiffened by the application of mild electrical currents, they could be triggered by traditional nerve impulses but a secondary power system will be needed to supply A. enough energy and B. the right kind of energy since nerve impulses are not in the form of electrical current. Anyone equipped with such a system will still need to eat, and in fact may need to increase their calorie intake as well as eating some rather strange supplements in order to maintain the system in use.

Now there are several issues here; Energy, how is that electrical power supplied, I would suggest a custom chemical-to-electric energy conversion, think of it as a battery but with the chemicals supplied by diet. Repair, ideally the artificial muscles are maintained by the same system that keeps the rest of the body going but if not then how are they repaired and how often? Chemical make up, the best existing candidates for this application are extremely toxic, if the body breaks that material down the host is going to die. Immune response, if the body doesn't treat the new material as at least inert, preferably as native tissue, then it will be attacked, breaking down the implants but more importantly causing a systemic response that would kill the host.

Comment: So if they could be triggered by nerve impulses then why would it need a secondary power supply? What about if there was some sort of implant in the brain to supply power from brain function?

Comment: @C.Dixon Because nerves don't carry current, at all, let alone enough current and voltage to cause sustained deformation of piezoelectric compounds. You're talking about hundreds of volts.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nerve-impulse according to this definition nerves do carry electrical current, and again what if there was some implant to convert brain function into electrical energy?

Comment: @C.Dixon See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) on the actual mechanism of nerve transmission, it's an ion exchange not a direct electron transmission.

Comment: @C.Dixon Not that much DC electricity no.

Comment: Ok that makes sense so looks like im going to have to rethink my cyborg soldier then.

Comment: @C.Dixon You could use a specialised digestive pathway to create the electricity you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is some interesting medical technology being done using 3D printers to print bone replacement parts, rather than transplanting donor bones:

> To make a good framework for filling in missing bone, mix at least 30 percent pulverized natural bone with some special man-made plastic and create the needed shape with a 3-D printer. That’s the recipe for success reported by researchers at The Johns Hopkins University in a paper published April 18 online in ACS Biomaterials Science & Engineering.

Find the full article [here](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/news/media/releases/the_search_for_better_bone_replacement_3_d_printed_bone_with_just_the_right_mix_of_ingredients_).

Conceivably, in a not-too distant future something similar might be achieved for replacing soft tissue, ranging from organs to muscles.

As for powering this, should external power be required, the recipient of this technology might be equipped with a implanted rechargeable battery, or if science comes up with the solution, a device similar to Iron Man's chest arc reactor. One could make further changes to the patient to allow ingested food to be turned into electricity, but that would complicate matters greatly, as changing one thing would require changing another, until the entire person is artificial.

Nerves do use/generate electricity, but the process is bio-chemical in nature so your artificial muscles would either have to be adapted to be able to interface with the nerves and the rest of the body as normal muscles do, or the nervous system would have to be reworked, leading to similar problems as described above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to some microbe-scale engineering, as long as there is no hard-science tag, you could think of artificial muscle tissues that operate similarly to clusters of hydraulic presses, one on top of the other. This system could be powered by stripes of microbial fuel cells. Some benefits and drawbacks are listed below.

#### The cellular hydraulic press

First of all, your artificial muscle is like a sponge filled with water. The basic idea is that instead of contracting muscle fibers, we extend them by filling them with water. The water is recalled into the "sponge" by osmotic pressure, which is itself controlled by the nerve signal activating a voltage difference. For this purpose, the cavities of the sponge are cells. There will be two types of cells:

- a "piston" cell, which is a soft cell cased in two rigid cylinders (open at the two ends) made of carbon chains (e.g. cellulose, polysaccharides, or proteins). The two cylinders can slide relative to one another, and they are held together by a cylindric seal made of proteins. For the sake of completeness, the seal is elastic, and always recalls the two cylinders together. The soft cell inside is attached to the rigid encasing by matching rings of biotin and streptavidin (think super-glue). The bottom and top of these soft cells are covered by ion pumps and water channels. These cells are filled with reservoirs of Chlorine Ions.
- a "dam" cell, which wraps the anode of the bacterial fuel cell. The cell is a bag of H+ produced by the fuel cell, and actively sucks water molecules from the environment, thus spending excess H+ production from the battery. It is covered in voltage dependent ion channels.

When the nerve activates, it depolarizes the membrane of the "dam" cell, thus opening the H+ ion channels, and releasing additional water molecules as well in the intercellular space. The ions flow freely causing a voltage difference between the "piston" cells and their environment. The voltage difference causes depolarization of the "piston" cells membrane, leading to release the Chlorine ions from the reservoirs inside the cellular plasma. The release of Cl-, which were in equilibrium between cells and the environment, further amplifies the voltage difference and causes osmotic pressure. Water is pumped inside the "piston" cells, elongating them, and causing the muscle to stretch. For each water molecule, an H+ is also taken inside the cell, and used to produce ATP.

When the nerve impulse ceases, the "dam" cell closes the ion channels, and starts pumping in water again. The "piston" cell first releases water due to hydrostatic pressure (remember the elastic seal), then uses ATP to pump Cl- back in the internal reservoirs, and finally pumps out water in the intercellular space, recovering further ATP in the process.

#### The energy source

[Microbial fuel cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell). These can be arranged in thin films, which could be wrapped around the artificial limb. The microbes will require some form of nutrient or external energy source (e.g. the sun), or both.

#### Benefits and drawbacks

- Partially self-repairing. The microbes will self-repair. The cells will self-repair. The actual arrangement of cells, and fuel cells films may not self-repair.
- Runs on glucose and solar power. Very convenient. The glucose could be supplied by the blood stream, provided filters to prevent the immune system from killing the microbes, and to prevent the microbes from going elsewhere.
- The thin fuel cell films could be coated in a transparent material that is more resistant than skin to scratches and cuts. For instance some polysaccharide polymer.
- It may not work very well at very low temperatures, or in prolonged darkness. Also, for power generation relying on a mediating element, there could be extremely toxic compounds just laying around in the fuel cells, leading to interesting plot twists.

#### Disclaimers

Note that in hard-science terms, I am not fully sure that this fully satisfies the 2nd principle of thermodynamics.

If anyone is interested, I can try to produce a graph.